# check 2 continues value in a list

Tags: python, list

i have a python script like this:

```
B = [[50,60],[40,20],[20,40],[150,200]]
List_New = []
for i in B :
    test = [y - x for x, y in zip(i[:-1], i[1:])]
    List_New += test
print(List_New)
```

result `[10, -20, 20, 50]`

i want to check 2 continues value in List_New if value From positive to negative goes print Index of that values as below :
`index=[0,1]`

Comment: Can you define what is your expected output?

Comment: print index of values in list that goes from positive value to negative value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use enumerate to get which index `i` carries negative value and also can `i-1` is positive or not. If the condition match then put it to the list.

```
[(i-1, i) for i, x in enumerate(List_New) if List_New[i]<0 and List_New[i-1]>=0]
```